# Connection and Insertion to Mysql Database Using php

Tags: php, mysql

As I am using PHP to connect to mysql database. I tried to connect to database and similarly I want to insert data into Database whenever I click to login button on my form. But no changes are shown db when I try this code so please any help with it. Thank you..

```
<?php
        $servername = "localhost"; 
        $username = "root";
        $password = "password";
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=Akalpa", $username, $password); // connection to my sql database

        if(isset($_POST['Log In'])){
            $username=$_POST['username'];
            $query = "Insert into User(username) values('$username')"; //query to insert to db

            if (mysql_query($query)) //checking the query 
            {
                echo"<h3>Inserted Successfully</h3>";   //value inserted to db successfully           
            }       


        }
    ?>
```

Comment: Just replace `mysql_query($query)` with `$conn->query( $query )` and look at Jack M's answer, because you should be doing more to be safe.

Answer (score 2):

It appears as though you are making a PDO connection but using mysql_ functions.
You should have your code written like this instead.

```
<?php
        $servername = "localhost"; 
        $username = "root";
        $password = "password";
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=Akalpa", $username, $password); // connection to my sql database

    if(isset($_POST['Log In'])){
        $username=$_POST['username'];
        $query = "INSERT INTO User(username) VALUES(:username)"; //query to insert to db
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute(["username"=>$username]);
        if ($result) //checking the query 
        {
            echo"<h3>Inserted Successfully</h3>";   //value inserted to db successfully           
        } else {
            die("query failed");
        }       


    }
?>
```

Your original code was susceptible to SQL injection, which is not good. I would also not reccommend using $_POST["Log In"] because it is terrible practice to have spaces in an array key. Try something simpler such as "submit" or just "login".